# get the data from dropdown list show error in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

In my project want to get patient name from DB and Insert new row to another table using the selected patient id.

patient.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('secondvisit.store')}}" method="post" >
{{csrf_field()}}        
<select name="ppid" id="select1" style="width: 200px"   >
  @foreach(\App\patient::all() as $pname)
  <option value="{{$pname->pid}}">{{$pname->fname}} {{$pname->mname}} {{$pname->lname}} </option>
  @endforeach  
</select>
</form>
```

In PatientController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {       
        $ob=new SecondVisit();
        $ob->pid=$request->input('ppid'); //tested by get('ppid')      
        $ob->vagbl=$request->input('vagbl');
        $ob->save();
        return redirect(route('secondvisit.index'));
    }
```

and when click the save button the below exception accour that say the pid is null

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'pid' cannot be null
```

Comment: Can you check `pid` column value. If `$pname->pid` may be null found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Process is Correct ..I think You Model name is Incorrect 
patient is start from small letter...check your model name please.I think it would be Patient.

Or,Show Your Data that every column should have pid. Check that any column is miss it or not

Comment: I tested by static option it worked 
<option value="11"> test </option>

Comment: tanku the problem is founded. id is correct not pid